# deleting data from from firebase and recyclerview

Tags: java, firebase

I am fairly new to firebase and im scouring the internet and forums about this problem, so the alert dialog is working but its not deleting any data on my firebase realtime database, what i want to happen is to delete the data and also delete the entry of that data in the recyclerview.

heres the code to the adapterview

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Model> mList;
Context context;
Task<Void> databaseReference;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> mList){
    this.mList = mList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item , parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model model = mList.get(position);
    holder.firstname.setText(model.getFirstname());
    holder.lastname.setText(model.getLastname());
    holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
    holder.mobilenumber.setText(model.getMobilenumber());
    holder.wash.setText(model.getWash());
    holder.dry.setText(model.getDry());
    holder.fold.setText(model.getFold());
    holder.press.setText(model.getPress());
    holder.weight.setText(model.getWeight());
    holder.totalprice.setText(model.getTotalprice());


    holder.buttondelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.firstname.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Delete Panel");
            builder.setMessage("Delete...?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String useridd = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Soft Orders")
                            .child(useridd).removeValue();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
   });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView firstname, lastname, address, mobilenumber, wash, dry, fold, press, weight, totalprice;
    Button buttondelete;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        firstname = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewfirstname);
        lastname = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewlastname);
        address = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewaddress);
        mobilenumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewmobilenumber);
        wash = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewwash);
        dry = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewdry);
        fold = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewfold);
        press = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewpress);
        weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewweight);
        totalprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Textviewtotalprice);
        buttondelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id. Buttondelete);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add firebase Tag please, so you get help fast

Comment: Very Good ..  :)